# Bucket sort + Thread

Tags: c++, thread

Estou tendo o seguinte erro neste codigo:

```
#define TAM 10000 /*Tamanho do vetor*/
#define NUM 10000 /*base para gerador de numeros aleatorios*/

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

pthread_t thread[TAM];

void gerarVet(long*);
void bucketSort(long*);
void imprimaVet(long*);

int main(){

    long vet[TAM],tinicio,tfim,tempo, i, Troca=0;
    long rt1, rt2;

   tinicio=time(NULL);

   gerarVet(vet);
   //imprimaVet(vet);

    do {

        Troca = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < TAM; i+=2)
        {       
            pthread_t t = thread[i];
            rt1 = pthread_create(&t, NULL, bucketSort(vet), (void*) &i);
        }
        for(i = 0; i < TAM; i+=2)
            pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);  

        Troca = 0;

        for(i = 1; i < TAM; i+=2)
        {
            pthread_t t = thread[i];
            rt2 = pthread_create(&t, NULL, bucketSort(vet), (void*)&i);
        }

        for(i = 1; i < TAM; i+=2)
            pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);


    } while(Troca == 1);

   //bucketSort(vet);   
   imprimaVet(vet);
```

Mensagem de erro:

```
39  79  C:  [Error] invalid use of void expression
49  61  C:  [Error] invalid use of void expression
```

Comment: Não tenho absoluta certeza se é esse o problema, mas você não deveria armazenar o ponteiro da thread no vetor `thread` *após* tê-la criado? Quando você cria a thread e recebe o ponteiro em `t`, você simplesmente o ignora e posteriormente usa o valor de `thread[i]` que não aponta para uma área necessariamente correta... Certo? Teste passando `&thread[i]` no lugar de `&t`, na chamada de `pthread_create`.

Comment: Nao deu certo... tentei fazer ele(i) assumir um ponteiro, mas continuo com o mesmo problema

Comment: Você está passando um ponteiro para uma variável local (i) por referência? Isso não é receita para desastre?

Answer (score 1):

A definição da função [pthread_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) é

```
   int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

Como podes ver pela definição, a função `pthread_create` espera como terceiro argumento uma função com a seguinte assinatura:

`void *f(void *)`;

A tua função `bucketSort` tem assinatura:

```
void bucketSort(long *)
```

Daí a mensagem de erro:

`Error] invalid use of void expression`

Answer (score 0):

tentei passar pra void, mas da o seguinte erro

[Warning] pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
[Error] 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type

Comment: Ola Gustavo, esta área vc pode postar a solução do seu problema como resposta. Faça um tour para vc aprender a usar o site:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Além de mudar a assinatura você precisa dar um *cast* na variavel antes de fazer operação com ela.

```
void funcao( void * long_var )  {
    long plus1 = *(long*)long_var + 1;
}
```